# The DSC provisioner could not be found

Tags: powershell, vagrant, windows-10, packer, dsc

I am trying to build a local development environment with vagrant, Packer And DSC.

And I have an error saying that DSC is not found, from my understanding DSC come with Powershell 4.0 and I checked the version I have it is 5.0 (I tried to install with INSTALL-MODULE and nothing change)

[image]

I am following this blog post : http://www.onegeek.com.au/articles/machine-factories-part1-vagrant
Running in windows 10
And here is the vagrant file I use https://gist.github.com/mefellows/7e25d5dba254d5d38b51#file-vagrantfile

The error message is :

[image]

Comment: Always post as much information about your issue as possible. What's the DSC error you ran into for example?

Comment: Sorry it was not explicit but the error message is the title of the post - I edited the post

Comment: That'a not a DSC error message. What happens when you build the mof manually with your MyWebsite.ps1 configuration script and apply it with `Start-DscConfiguration -Wait -Verbose -Path <path to folder that contains your mof>`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to install the Vagrant DSC plugin first:

`vagrant plugin install vagrant-dsc`

See https://github.com/mefellows/vagrant-dsc for more details.

I have updated the [gist](https://gist.github.com/mefellows/7e25d5dba254d5d38b51#file-run-vagrant-sh) from that article, apologies for that omission.